# How to call Main Method from another Class in Java as a Process

Tags: java, class, process, program-entry-point

I have this 2 classes:

```
public class Sumador {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int primerNumero = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int segundoNumero = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int suma = 0;
        
        for(int k=primerNumero; k < segundoNumero; k++) {
            suma += k;
        }
        System.out.println("Resultado: " + suma);
    }
}
```

```
public class Lanzador {
    
    public void lanzarSumador() {
        Process p;
        InputStream is;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        
        try {
            p = new ProcessBuilder("java", "Sumador.java", "10", "20").start();
            is = p.getInputStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while(br.ready()) {
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
            }
            
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lanzador l = new Lanzador();
        l.lanzarSumador();
        
    }
}
```

What i want to do is running the second class to get the first one as a process in the second one, but unfortunetly for me, it doesn't work and i can't understand why.

Every reply would be really thankful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what you are asking. Do you wish to call `Sumador.main` from `Lanzador.main`? If so there should be no issues with that so please give some details on what isn't working. Or are you looking to run `Sumador` as a separate Java program within `Lanzador`? If so, please explain why as this is a pretty unusual thing to do in Java.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69560514/having-trouble-calling-class-to-process-on-intellij

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
You can call the main method of class Sumador from the main method in class Lanzador like show next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lanzador l = new Lanzador();
    l.lanzarSumador();
    Sumador.main(null);
}
```

You only can have one main class in your program execution. What you can do is change the main method in class Sumador at a public class and call it in the main method of class Lanzador

```
public class Sumador {

public static void sumadorMethod() {
    int primerNumero = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int segundoNumero = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int suma = 0;
    
    for(int k=primerNumero; k < segundoNumero; k++) {
        suma += k;
    }
    System.out.println("Resultado: " + suma);
}
```

}

Then you main method in class Lanzador look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lanzador l = new Lanzador();
    l.lanzarSumador();
    Sumador.sumadorMethod();
}
```

Comment: Your answer is misleading. There is no problem at all having several `public static main(String[])` methods inside a single Java program. They can quite happily call each other without issues. Which `main` is the entry point to the code is defined externally to the code.

Comment: You're right, my bad. You can call the main method in the class Sumador like {Sumador.main(null);} I'll edit my response to evade misunderstandings. 
Regards